# Program can't read integer values

Tags: python, string, variables, types, int

The following code is to check variables and output(print) a  value. The only output I get is `One value is a string` when run on anaconda 3.6 despite the variable type (`int`, `float` or `str`). However it runs perfectly on DataCamp platform on Programiz.com Please where did I go wrong. Below is the code:

```
essa1 = input("please enter essa1")
essa2 = input("please enter essa2")
if type(essa1) == str and  type(essa2) != str:
    print("One value is a string")
elif type(essa1) == int and type(essa2) == int:
    if essa1 == essa2:
        print("the two variables are equal")
    elif essa1 < essa2:
        print("essa1 is bigger")
    else:
        print("essa1 is now smaller")
else:
    print("One value is a string")
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because `input()` is always read as a `str`.

If you read the value `42`, you are actually reading the value `"42"` of type `str`. Only if you cast it to an `int` or `float` etc. will the value change types.

```
i = input('enter an int') # type 42 and press enter
# i now contains the string value "42"
i = int(i) # cast value to type int
# i now contains the int value 42
```

If you want to check that your string value contains an int before attempting to cast it, you might try `i.isdigit()` which will return true if the string contains only digits.

Comment: There isn't a `double` in Python, it's a `float`

Comment: Good point. Updated.

Comment: Sorry guys for the delay in response was trying Sears to fix the stuff.

Comment: Thanks the_storyteller for your contribution. But please note that the program isn't designed to output statements with regards to the input, be it integers or strings. If I cast it the way you said, it throws an error.